# If $f(x)$ belong to set of probability distributions, then what can be deduced about $\frac{1}{a} f(\frac{1}{a}\cdot x)$

Tags: probability-distributions

My question is in the context of probability distributions, whose Fourier transforms (characteristic function) almost always exit.

If $f(x)$ be some function such that $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx=1,$

then what can be said/deduce about $ \frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(\frac{1}{a}x\right) \, dx,$ where $a \in \mathbb{R^+}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: use change of variable $z=\frac{x}{a}$.

Comment: It turns out that  $ \frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{a}x)dx=1$ too. Hence it is also a probability distribution. IS this correct?

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}f(\frac{1}{a}x)$ can indeed be considered a probability density (provided that $f\geq 0$).

Comment: yes ofcourse, if $f(x)$ is some distribution then it is for sure that $f \ge 0$ and so is $f(ax) \ge 0.$